# Как отправить случайные фото с подписью из списка кортежей

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Пытаюсь сделать бота с рандомным выводом текста с картинкой, но уперся в проблему, не знаю как дальше `torot_list` прописать функцию для вывода.

```py
import telebot
from telebot import types # для указание типов
from datetime import datetime
import config
import random
import json


bot = telebot.TeleBot('')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn = types.KeyboardButton("")
    markup.add(btn)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет, {0.first_name}!\nХочешь узнать своё будущее?\nЖми на всевидящее око \nНо будь осторожен,ведь чем меньше знаешь тем крепче спишь❗".format(message.from_user), reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text', 'photo'])
def func(message):
    if(message.text == ""):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("")
        markup.add(btn1)

        tarot_list = [
            ('img/image1.png', 'Текст 1'),
            ('img/image2.png', 'Текст 2'),
        ]
        
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, random.choice(tarot_list))

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Comment: ну типо делай. чо помоч то?

Comment: @Эникейщик не могу понять как вывести лист

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Эникейщик эх..уже который раз вместо помощи я получаю советы как правильно объяснять, спасибо учту!

Comment: @BlackMist так мне кажется все логично — пока правильно не объяснишь с чем помочь, никто не поймет как и в чем помогать :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй так

```py
from telebot.types import InputFile

tarot_list = [
    ('img/image1.png', 'Текст 1'),
    ('img/image2.png', 'Текст 2'),
]
rand_photo, rand_text = random.choice(tarot_list)

bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=InputFile(rand_photo), caption=rand_text)
```

Comment: Помогло, спасибо огромное!